# Why Visual studio can't Identify `string` instead of `String`?

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

Why Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise version is not supported to the default formation of C++, I used Code-Blocks for a long time and still using it. Code Blocks was my first IDE to start with C++ and now for the graphical interface I use Visual Studio but when it comes to editing the source code, Visual Studio is not accepting many things that is accepted in Code-Blocks. A little example is declaring a `string` in visual studio is not acceptable but it needs to be `String` to work properly.
Maybe this is a Compiler Issue but I am not familiar with all Compilers, I used minGW in Codeblocks.
[image: Source Image]

Comment: You must `#include <string>` and it must be `std::string` unless you are `using namespace std;` ([which is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). Please show a [mre].

Comment: The standard library has class `std::string`, Arduino has it's own `String`, I don't of any other variations.

Comment: Did you `#include <string>` and `using std::string`?

Comment: Read [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: @SimonC Yes the string is included

Comment: This is not C++ though. It's C++/CLI if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I created an empty project c++/clr

Comment: @Саша If you're targeting the CLR, you're most likely programming in C++/CLI, not C++, and from what I see in your picture it sure does look like it. (`System::Object^ sender` wouldn't even compile in C++)

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's mean the question should be closed?

Comment: @Саша No, no, it's enough to put the correct tag on it (which I did) I think.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am not about the tag correction, but I think my question is totally incorrect, I must learn about C++/CLI and come back to VS

Answer (score 0):

What you'll find is you're not including the string header, nor are you actually referencing the std::string object.

To import:

```cpp
#include <string>

using std::string; // This is optional, but it saves you from having to type std::string all the time.
```

Comment: Actually, typing `std::string` in full makes much more readable code...

Comment: string is included

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I beg to differ. I find it much less readable, as it adds no more information to the code.

Comment: @Саша But you're not `using` the string anywhere, as far as I can tell. If your file is empty, paste the code here so we can all read it.

Comment: @SimonC The project is empty but it has 500 lines of code generated by VS in it's .h file in which I am editing the code

Comment: Learn wxWidgets as your GUI toolkit instead of CLI.